# Preg_match and percent sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, sign

I have few questions regarding preg_match in php.

```
if(preg_match('#[^0-9 -&()+@._A-Za-z]#', $input)){
    $errors .= 'Sorry, username can\'t contain those characters.<br>';
}
```

This is my `preg_match`. I am kinda new to these codes. I have red that its better to use `#` on the end and beginning than `/` for unknown reason xD
Anyone knows what is up with that?

My main problem is that this `preg_match` actually let strings with `%` (percent signs) through and it shouldn't. Why? and how to stop that?

Another question is this `preg_match` code good?
It works fine (except `%` part) but can it fail?

Thank you :)

Comment: The `#` instead of `/` is because `/` is used in URLs and will need to be escaped in every instance. I prefer `~` because it is rarely used in data I'm parsing. Also these are referred to as delimiters, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: What is that even for? I mean first and last character (#,~,/)?

Comment: They are delimiters they tell the regex engine where the expression starts and ends. `When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters` See that link at the end of my first comment.

Comment: So in my case it does not even matter witch ones I use?

Comment: Not currently, if you were to add `#` to the list of characters not allowed though you would need to escape it `\#` or change the delimiters to an unused character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> this preg_match actually let strings with "%" (percent signs) through and it shouldn't. Why?

That is due to unescaped hyphen in the middle of your regex:

```
'#[^0-9 -&()+@._A-Za-z]#'
--------^
```

`-` is acting as range from space (32) to `&` (38) thus matching anything in between including `%` ( 37).

It should be used as:

```
'#[^-0-9 &()+@._A-Za-z]#'
```

Or

```
'#[^-\w &()+@.]#'
```

However without anchors this character class will match only one character. You should use:

```
'#^[^-\w &()+@.]+$#'
```

Comment: Should probably use **anchors** as well.

Comment: dat ascii range explanation tho <3

Comment: Nice explanation thank you. I understand now. Where i can find a table for characters and their meaning in the code?
I tried to find it but I failed.

Comment: On Linux/Unix you can just use `man ascii` on [see it online](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/ascii/)

Comment: Oh I didn't mean ascii characters i meant code characters inside preg_match parameter.

Comment: You can get all the info here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: Ofcourse I just wanted to find out as much as i could. Thank you everyone! :)

Comment: one more question,what are anchors? :S

Comment: `^` and `$` are called anchors in regex for assessing start and end position respectively.

Comment: I tested all preg_match-es you wrote and the last one (the one with anchors) isn't working well. But the '#[^-\w &()+@.]#' works pretty good :)

Comment: Hmm that can be possible only if you anything other than `[^-\w &()+@.]` in your input data. Can you show output of `var_dump($input);`

Comment: I used https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html for testing i input random characters...with last preg_match its all true :S